# Inject EntityManager into embedded FormTypes with Symfony2 3.0+

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dependency-injection, entitymanager

Short question: How can I inject the EntityManager into embedded form types in symfony2 3.0+? **Note: I mentioned embedded form types, not just the parent form**

Long question:
In previous versions of Symfony2 (<2.6) I found myself in the need of the following: I have an entity A which has an entity B which has an entity C, each entity has it's own form and in each entity form type I have the need to use the entity manager.

In previous versions I did the following in the controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$a = new A();
$form = $this->createForm(new AType($em), $a);
```

Then in the AType I was able to use the $em in the constructor and continue to pass it down to the childs:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('b', new BType($this->em))
    ;
}
```

And in BType.php I would do the same in the buildForm to pass the $em to CType.

The problem I am facing now is that in order for you to define embedded forms in symfony2 3.0+ you have to do something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(AType::class, $a);
```

Doing it this way without having access to the controller leaves me only (that I know of) with one option, defining the form as a service. With this option I have 2 problems, one is that as they specify in their documentation this should be used if the form is going to be used in several parts of your application, in this case this form is just going to be on one section of the application and I have that A-B-C hierarchy in order to have a proper database structure (something like a Company > Owner > Employee relationship). My other concern is that if I define the form as a service I am aware that I can use:

```
$form = $this->createForm('servicename', $a);
```

in the controller and that would inject the EntityManager, but what about BType and CType, how could I inject the EntityManager into them using AType as a service?

My last idea/attempt that I think is very ugly is defining A,B,C as a service and building the form in the controller.

Comment: You can always resort to using the third argument of `createForm()`, `$options` and pass `EntityManager` from there. You can later on access it from `$options` in your `buildForm` method.

Comment: Do I have to pass it through the "attr"=>array() of the $options?

Comment: `em` should still be available as a default option, so passing an array like `array('em' => $entityManager)` should do the trick.

Comment: You may be over thinking this.  Just define your form types as services.  The injections will always then always happen.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: @Artamiel If I try to do $form = $this->createForm(AType::class, $a, array('em' => $em)); I get The option "em" does not exist. Defined options are: bla bla, I could include it in the 'attr' option but I really don't want to get that messy.. I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: @Cerad I don't know if I took a pill of stupidity or something, but in the new documentation they don't even include an example of how to use the form after you define it as a service... I followed their instructions on how to add the form as a service, and since in the 3.0 there is no example I am assuming it would be the same as previous version so I am trying $form = $this->createForm($this->get('service'), $a); and also without the $this->get, because I am getting this error: Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\AType" given.

Comment: @Cerad I at first thought that I was in fact overthinking this, because this should be pretty straight forward just as previous version, but think about it, now the createForm method receives a plain string instead of a form type. So now I can't even get past the createForm, either like I said I took a pill of stupidity or Symfony really moved things around without properly documenting it on their documentation page..

Comment: Sure, you always pass the class name.  But the form system takes care of using the container for classes that have been defined as services.  It's the same approach as S2 when using aliases.  Just replacing aliases with class names.  Define services for your three form types.  Everything should work just fine.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks man! I just realized that, I performed the tests when I saw your other comments I was kind of skeptical because before you had to search for the service yourself, I didn't know that SF2 did this in the background now.. it worked! I left a detailed explanation on the answer in case someone else has this confusion.

Comment: @all, still there? Nice post, since I am fighting with exactly the same issue. I understand how to define a service, but I would like to do the old way, to  pass 'em' as an option? @ Artamiel, did you fix your suggestion? Please let me know.

Comment: @mario can't you pass it in the constructor? I figured that's way easier and cleaner than in the options...However, I am not sure why you want to do it the old way since defining services is way less painful as SF2 takes care of passing the EM for you..are you by any chance running transactions or anything like it?

Comment: @Ben. Thanks for your reply. Really, just out of lazyness (and ignorance), no transactions. When you say "pass in the constructor", you mean when I have defined the service (as in your solution), don't you? Otherwise, I do not get it.

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured this out with @Cerad

```
app.form.a:
    class: AppBundle\Form\AType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app.form.a }

app.form.b:
    class: AppBundle\Form\BType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app.form.b }

app.form.c:
    class: AppBundle\Form\CType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app.form.c }
```

And then in the controller when you call:

```
$form = $this->createForm(AType::class, $a);
```

Apparently Symfony2 in the background looks for the service and injects the dependencies, my confusion was that before you had to call the service yourself when using createForm... I did not see any documentation about this..

Then, in the types when you do:

```
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('b', BType::class)
    ;
}
```

Symfony will take care of injecting the dependencies of BType as well if you define it as a service.

Thanks @Cerad! your comment made me perform this test!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the alias tag is gone in Symfony 3.  Does not hurt but no longer does anything.